# Invalid use of non-static member function In instantiation of member function of a class template?

Tags: c++, c++11, generic-programming

I want a class template to start some number of threads to test some functions, which access some shared states.

```
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

template<std::size_t M, std::size_t N>
class A {
public:
    void test(std::size_t n) {
        std::vector<std::thread> ts;
        for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
            ts.push_back(
                    std::thread( A::foo, this, i, n )
            );
        }
        for(auto& thread : ts){
            thread.join();
        }
    }

private:
    void foo( std::size_t tid, std::size_t n ) {
    }
};

int main() {
    A<10, 2> tester;
    tester.test(1000);
}
```

This gives following error. Why and how to fix?

```
prog.cpp: In instantiation of 'void A<M, N>::test(std::size_t) [with unsigned int M = 10u; unsigned int N = 2u; std::size_t = unsigned int]':
prog.cpp:27:18:   required from here
prog.cpp:11:27: error: invalid use of non-static member function
          threads.push_back(
```

**Edit:**

It compiles after changing to `std::thread( &A::foo, this, i, n )` as @Igor suggested. As far as I understand, function name decay to a pointer when passing into a function. Why do we still need the ampersand '&'?

Comment: Make it `std::thread(&A::foo, this, i, n )`. Note the ampersand.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Answers go down there: ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

Comment: You need the ampersand because that's the syntax for forming a pointer to member function.

Comment: Non-static member functions do not decay to pointers-to-members.

Answer (score 2):

Re: why the ampersand is required. Because the standard says so.

> **[expr.prim.general]/13** An *id-expression* that denotes a non-static data member or non-static member function of a class can only be used:
>
> (13.1) — as part of a class member access (5.2.5) in which the object expression refers to the member's class or a class derived from that class, or
>
> (13.2) — to form a pointer to member (5.3.1), or
>
> (13.3) — if that *id-expression* denotes a non-static data member and it appears in an unevaluated operand.

And further:

> **[expr.ref]/4** ...one of the following rules applies.
>
> (4.3.2) — Otherwise, if `E1.E2` refers to a non-static member
>   function... [t]he expression can be used only as the left-hand operand
>   of a member function call (9.3)...

So basically, `A::foo` can legally appear only with the ampersand in front ("to form a pointer to member") or with the opening paren following ("left-hand operand of a function call").